About the normal subgroups of Burnside groups
I was reading "On Periodic Groups of Odd Period $n\geq1003$" of V. S. Atabekyan. He found that the Burnside group $B_n$ with $n\geq 1003$ has uncountable many normal subgroups. However, I was wondering if the intersection of these are trivial or not; to be precise, if the intersection of all the non-trivial normal subgroups is trivial or not.
Clearly, the Burnside group is not residually finite at least for large $n$, but I do not know, and cannot prove if it has a monolith or not. I think this is something that should really be well known, so this is why I'm asking here, because I cannot find it.

It would be helpful if you were more specific here. Do you mean the intersection of (1) all normal subgroups, (2) all non-trivial normal subgroups, or (3) all normal subgroups with simple quotient? I presume you don't mean (1), so the obvious choice is (2), but as the paper deals with the subgroups in (3), this is perhaps the case you mean?

I mean (2). If it is possible also (3).

I am not sure why you expect the answer to this question to be well known! You could try asking it on mathoverflow.

OK. Also, I'm confused as to why it is "clear" than these groups are not residually finite? There do exist residually finite periodic groups, e.g. Grigorchuk-like groups. [Also, I've never heard of a "monolith" before. It may be helpful to define it, or simply not use the word.]

Ah - non-residual finiteness follows from Zelmanov's solution to the Restricted Burnside Problem. This is only applicable for groups of bounded exponent. So finitely generated residually finite periodic groups have unbounded exponent, which is indeed the case for Grigorchuk-like groups. [But this is only "clear" if you happen to know the relevant result...]

A group G is said to be monolithic if the intersection M of all its non-trivial normal subgroups is non-trivial: in this case M is said to be the monolith of G.
